# GChart Text Color and axis labels

Tags: java, gwt

I am using a GChart in my web app and cannot find any information about chaging the color of the text on the X and Y axis.  My chart is being displayed within a HorizontalPanel within a StackPanel.  Here is my code for the GChart, not where it is displayed:

```
public class ChartTuple extends GChart {
public ChartTuple() {
    super();
    setChartTitle("<b></b>");
    setChartSize(400,300);
    addCurve();
    for (double i = 01.24; i < 14; i++) {
        System.out.println("Adding curve PT");
        getCurve().addPoint(i, i);
    }

    getCurve().getSymbol().setSymbolType(SymbolType.VBAR_SOUTH);
    getCurve().getSymbol().setBackgroundColor("red");
    getCurve().getSymbol().setBorderColor("gray");
    getCurve().getSymbol().setModelWidth(0.5);
    getXAxis().setAxisLabel(
            "<b>Latency Distribution (% objects, time in mm:ss)</b>");
    getXAxis().setHasGridlines(false);
    getYAxis().setAxisLabel("");
    getYAxis().setHasGridlines(true);
    addStyleName("chart-text");
    System.out.println(getCurve());
    System.out.println(this.toString());
    setVisible(true);
} }
```

Thank you Very Much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code is how you change the colors of the X Y axis label.

```
getXAxis().setTickLabelFontColor("white");
    getYAxis().setTickLabelFontColor("white");
```